# Creating a new member account (without the accompanying profile channel entry) with Profile:Edit

Tags: members, profile-edit

Using Profile:Edit, is there a way to create a new member account, without creating the profile channel entry at the same time? I've got a situation where I have profile channel entries already created, but just need to create the member accounts separately on the front end.

Using the {exp:profile:register} tag creates both the member account and the profile channel entry (so I then end up with a duplicate profile channel entry as it already existed previously).

Just wondering if there's a non-documented parameter I can use to make it create just the member account, or if there's any ideas for an alternative method (SQL, Database class, etc), thanks.

Comment: Can you not sync your member profiles from your Profile:Edit channel to your member profiles? How many are we talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to use something like [Stand-Alone Member Registration](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/stand-alone-member-register) to create the new profiles from the front-end but I'm not sure how in sync you need those to be with your existing Profile:Edit channel entries? That will create the member entries at least.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that out. They don't need to by in sync at all as that's what the Profile:Edit register tags do. So this is just for creating new member accounts on the front end, without creating the accompanying channel entry too.

Answer (score 3):

I think you'll need to just use a Safecracker form to create a regular old member account, and then on the backend use the Profile:Edit utility under the P:E Settings to associate that new member account with the existing P:E entry.

If you need this all to happen from the front-end, I'd dig into the P:E utility to see how it works and maybe reuse that code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. SafeCracker can't be used to create member accounts though, can it?

Comment: Unfortunately not, unless you used something like the [Safecracker Registration](https://objectivehtml.com/safecracker-registration) addon. This however would still look to create a channel entry.